# How to redirect with react router V6 in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to redirect to "/" , I am currently at "/register" route . If the response is ok then the page should be redirected to "/" path . I am trying to create a single page application with react js .

```
if(response.ok){
    console.log("ok");
    return redirect("/");
}
else{
    console.log("error");
}
```

Not being redirected to the specified route .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna have to make some assumptions about the setup, but if you're using `react-router-dom`, you can use its exported `useNavigate` hook

```
// in a component
const navigate = useNavigate()

const postSomeData = (data) => {
  fetch('.../something').then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log('ok')
      navigate('/')
    } else {
      console.log('error')
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assign the new location

```
if(response.ok){
    console.log("ok");
    window.location.assign("/");
    return;
}
else{
    console.log("error");
}
```

you should be using guard clauses like such, to reduce code complexity and also make code simple and easy to read, and no if, else chain:

```
// Handle Error
if(!response.ok){
    console.log("error");
    return;
}
// Handle Success
console.log("ok");
window.location.assign("/");
```